# Github Actions - copy files to VPS

Tags: github, ssh, copy, github-actions

I would like to solve this at a small VPS Provider:

Github worflow, when pushed files to GitHub, then "GH workflows" copies the php files to the live VPS server.

How can I copy them?

### `.github/workflows/vps-deploy-prod.yml`:

```yaml
name: vps-deploy-prod

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:

  build: 'VPS Run Deploy'
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest    
  steps:
    - name: 'Checkout'
      uses: action/checkout@master
    - name: 'Deploy'
      run: make vps-run-deploy
```

The Makefile:

```sh
##### VPS specific target
vps-run-deploy:

?? copy files via ssh scp...?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider the GitHub action [`appleboy/scp-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action)

[GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) for copying files and artifacts via SSH.

Here is an example in this project: [`renatomh/gobarber-backend/.github/workflows/main.yml`](https://github.com/renatomh/gobarber-backend/blob/0ba76866ddd0364ca305e037b7b84b05c67e22a8/.github/workflows/main.yml):

```yaml
      # Copy the repository to the directory on the server/VPS used for the application
      - name: Copy dist to VPS
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          # Selecting all folders except "node_modules"
          source: ".,!node_modules"
          # The path is based on the directory where the user logged into the server starts
          target: "~/app/gobarber-backend"
```

Comment: ok, thanks.
Can it be solved with Makefile?

Comment: @gabor No: the point of this answer is to illustrate you don't need a Makefile, because there is a GitHub Action which will do the `scp` (copy) for you.